# NextJS styling breaks upon leaving the page

Tags: next.js, styling, framer-motion

The website below is done using NextJS and Framer Motion for animations. The problem is that the styling breaks upon leaving the contact page, but everything works fine when navigating between other pages. The layout of the pages are basically the same and this problem doesn't happen on dev mode.

Website: [www.bensem.eu/contact](http://www.bensem.eu/contact)

GitHub: https://github.com/yuivae/bensem/blob/main/pages/contact.js

I would appreciate the help!

Thank you